# How to treat the "No instance found" of WMIC command in batch?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

In a batch I want to terminate all instance of a process.
I've try using:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%r in (`wmic process where Name^="CALC.exe"  get Processid ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do SET procid=%%~r
IF [!procid!] NEQ [] (
  wmic process where Name="CALC.exe" call terminate >> NUL
) ELSE (
  GOTO :break
)
:break
SET procid=
endlocal
```

But if no instance of calc.exe is existing I don't want to have the "No instance(s) available" being displayed. Also I will prefer to not have the display scrolling down one line per instance of calc.exe

How to do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I don't want to have the "No instance(s) available" being displayed.

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%r in (`wmic process where Name^="CALC.exe" get Processid ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do SET procid=%%~r
```

You can throw away the errors using the redirect operator `2> nul`

> Redirect to NUL (hide errors)
>
> `command 2> nul`

Notes:

- The `>` must be escaped using `^`.
- The `null` device is a special file that discards all data written to it, but reports that the write operation succeeded.

The `for` commmand becomes:

```
`wmic process where Name^="CALC.exe" get Processid 2^> nul ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`
```

---

#### Also I will prefer to not have the display scrolling down one line per instance of calc.exe

```
 wmic process where Name="CALC.exe" call terminate >> NUL
```

You can throw away the extra blank lines using the redirect operator `> NUL 2>&1`

The "terminate" command becomes:

```
wmic process where Name="CALC.exe" call terminate >NUL 2>&1
```

---

#### Putting it all together

Modified batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%r in (`wmic process where Name^="CALC.exe" get Processid 2^> nul ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do SET procid=%%~r
IF [!procid!] NEQ [] (
  wmic process where Name="CALC.exe" call terminate >NUL 2>&1
) ELSE (
  GOTO :break
)
:break
SET procid=
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.